# why should we use subscribe() over map() in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular-observable

I am trying to take advantage of observables in angular2 and got confused on why should i use `map()` over `subscribe()`.
Suppose i am getting values from a webApi, like this

```
  this.http.get('http://172.17.40.41:8089/api/Master/GetAllCountry')
```

Now using `subscribe(success, error, complete)` I can get all the values on the success callback and I can return the values on the complete callback. If I can do all theses functionalities then what is the need of `map()`? Does it give any advantage?

**In short, why one should write like this**:

```
this.http.get('http://172.17.40.41:8089/api/Master/GetAllCountry')
    .map(r=>{})
    .subscribe(value => {
    }, error => error, () => {
});
```

**when they can simply write this without the map function:**

```
this.http.get('http://172.17.40.41:8089/api/Master/GetAllCountry')
    .subscribe(value => {        
    }, error => error, () => {           
});
```

Comment: i have updated my  question, please have a look at it

Comment: .map(r=>{}) will result in undefined value. Please, explain your case in a reasonable way if you're looking for a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

If you want to return an `Observable` some other code can subscribe to, but you still want to manipulate the data events in the current method, use `map`.

The actual user of the observable needs to `subscribe()`, because without `subscribe()` the observable won't be executed at all. (`forEach()` or `toArray()` and probably others work as well to execute the observable instead of `subscribe()`)

`subscribe()` returns a `Subscription` that can not be subscribed to, but it can be used to cancel the subscription.

`map()` returns an `Observable` which can be subscribed to.

Comment: To add to the answer, operations in `map` are executed asynchronously whereas operations in `subscribe` are executed synchronously. There's a performance improvement, albeit probably not huge in most cases, to doing as much work as possible in the `map` call.

Answer (score 35):

Think map as a middleware which transforms the response.

```
this.http.get('http://172.17.40.41:8089/api/Master/GetAllCountry')
.map(r=>r.json())
 .subscribe(result => {
              // here result would have json object that was parsed by map handler...
            },failurCallback,completeCallback)
```

subscribe is used to invoke the observable, please read a good doc on [cold-vs-hot-observables](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/16/cold-vs-hot-observables.html)

Answer (score 18):

You need `subscribe` to run your async request. If you just set `map` - no requests will trigger. You can check.

Good practice to use `map` to preproccess you data because many subscribers can comsume your results. So instead of adding preprocessing to each client (subscriber) you can prepare single output with single data schema for all.

Comment: The first paragraph doesn't answer the question, as OP isn't asking whether to subscribe or not.

The second paragraph, however, is great. For some reason, the way you put it made more sense than the accepted answer for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Observables are streams and they are designed to be written in functional streams. You should use **RxJS** operations because it is the '*functional*' way of implementing subsctiptions to observables. Usually this happens when we take data outside of the Observable stream.

This is an asynchronous operation forced to work synchronously.

```
bad_example() {
  let id;
  this.obs.subscribe(param => id = param['id']);
    this.get(id).subscribe(elem => this.elem = elem);
}
```

This is an asynchronous operation that works as supposed to work.
(As a stream)

```
good_example() {
  this.obs
    .map(param => param['id'])
    .switchMap(id => return this.get(id))
    .subscribe(elem => this.elem = elem);
}
```

Comment: so in the bad example you have used a variable to store data, and in your good example as you claim, you have this private member! please distinguish your opinions from good & bad practices

Comment: This is an asynchronous operation forced to work synchronously , so I think it is a bad practice to do that

Answer (score 2):

`.map()` is an rxjs operator, it  will show the result in array `[]` form either `.json()` form

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html