# What are Observables and how does they make difference in HttpClient

Tags: angular, angular-observable

In angular, we have Observables which makes easier in handling HTTP requests. Along with there are functions like

> map(), subscribe(), pipe()

and I do not know much.

The problem I am facing here is, when to use this function, which is best suited for which situation? I am not at all following these.

Comment: Have you gone through the [Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/observables)

Comment: Yes, I have been, but not able to follow it :(

Comment: What are you not able to comprehend it clearly explains the usage of all the `operators` with examples

Comment: The subscriber and the consumer part.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42342781/why-should-we-use-subscribe-over-map-in-angular

Comment: Understand it by implement some of examples. Learning by doing!

Comment: @Antoniossss, Yes I want to do that, but I need some help. Can you please give me some examples with sample codes?

Answer (score 2):

This is a broad topic (could cover all of RxJS) but here are the basics.

**Observables** are objects that can *asynchronously* emit a value, and notify users when there is an error or no more objects will be emitted. You register to get values from an observable by using `subscribe` (ok, not technically the *only* way but its the usual and most basic one). They enable this sort of flow:

1. Observable created
2. You subscribe and print the emitted value (`obs.subscribe(v => console.log(v)`)
3. Time passes, stuff happens (the method where subscribe was called has long since returned)
4. The observable emits "Hello World"
5. The callback you passed in `subscribe` is called and "Hello World" is printed to the console.

These are useful in HTTP requests (through HttpClient) in particular because HTTP requests are inherently asynchronous. You put bytes on the wire and at some point bytes will come back. You don't want your website to freeze up while you wait though. Hence; the `HttpClient` methods return observables that you subscribe to in order to retrieve the request result.

As far as the methods you mentioned (`map`, `filter`, `pipe`) they are just helper methods that allow you to do various things to an observable as it emits. There are **lots** more and you can find a lot more about each in the documentation. A quick summary of `map` and `filter` (haven't used `pipe`):

- `map` takes a source observable and allows you to transform it into a different type of observable.
- `filter` creates an observable that only emits items from the source observable if a predicate is satisfied.