# Api call with id and key

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api

I want to get data from https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/nutrients for my calorie calculator . it needs x-app-id and x-app-key for authentication.

What i have tried :
(Service.ts)

```
fetchFood(){
  let url = 'https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/nutrients';
let headers = new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'x-app-id': 'aea728dc',
  'x-app-key': 'b945aeaf7ce6a860870f8686248a9485',
});
let query="banana"
let options = { headers: headers };
return this.http.post<any>(url, {query}, options).pipe(
  map((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  })
);

}
```

register.component.ts

```
  this.authService.fetchFood();
```

it Shows nothing when i console response.
is there any problem in api call??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `map` operator, which is used to alternate the response. Use `tap` operator instead.

```
return this.http.post<any>(url, {query}, options).pipe(
  tap((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the difference between subscribe and map [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42342781/why-should-we-use-subscribe-over-map-in-angular)

```
return this.http.post<any>(url, {query}, options).subscribe((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to a cold observable to trigger the request.

Register Component

```js
someHandler() {
  this.authService.fetchFood().subscribe({
    next: res => {
      console.log(res);
      // do something else
    },
    error: error => {
      // handle error
    }
  });
}
```

Additionally as mentioned in other answers, you could use `tap` instead of `map` operator in the service for logging. `map` is used to transform the response.